# Convert Image To Map Tiles In-App

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mbtiles, maptiler

I want to be able to convert a given image uploaded in the app and convert it to map tiles to be overplayed in a `MapView`. This could be a photo downloaded from the web or simply a photo taken from the device's camera.

I have so far come across GDAL2Tiles and [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com) but I want to be able to do this in the app instead of preparing them beforehand. These are command line and desktop applications that will do the conversion, but this is all that I can find so far.

Is there a built-in feature for iOS that allows me to do this? If not, is there a third-party library that does, or is it just not possible?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: no progress, opted for using map overlay images, but storing rotation/orientation was the next problem we faced (not fixed yet)

Comment: Take a look here: https://playcode.org/custom-offline-map-using-maptiler/, maybe it will help you about your rotation issue...